# WKT Representation won't display correctly in AWS Athena

Tags: string, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena, wkt

I have created a table which has a 'geometry' column that has geometries in WKT representation. I have saved this as a parquet file and uploaded to an S3 location and used AWS Athena to create a table using that parquet file. However the geometry column shows up as gibberish instead of a string.

For example

[image: geometry WKT showing up as gibberish]

Do I need to do something different in the CREATE TABLE step or is it a problem with the parquet compression? How can I resolve this?